# angular ng-repeat taking every character, not each entry in JSON

Tags: angularjs

So I'm learning AngularJS, and trying a simple pull of JSON into a table. when I do "ng-repeat" on a table row, repeats for every character in my JSON... and never finds the element.

my INDEX

```
<!doctype html >
<html ng-app="usersApp" >
    <head>

        <title>Simple AngularJS Application</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css" >

    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="container" >
            <div class="hero-unit" ng-view >
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="angular.min.js" ></script>
        <script src="angular-resource.min.js" ></script>
        <script src="main.js" ></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

my PARTIAL (list.html)

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>NAME</td>
            <td>TYPE</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
        <td>--&gt;</td><!-- NOTE: I added these tds to 'see' what was coming in -->
            <td>{{user}}</td>
            <td>{{user.id}}</td>
            <td>{{user.name}}</td>
            <td>{{user.type}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

my JSON

```
[{"id":"284","name":"JAMES IS AAA-DRIVER","type":"Employee"},
 {"id":"243,"name":"Brian J Adamms","type":"Employee"},
 {"id":"237,"name":"Test Agent","type":"Brokerage Agent"}];
```

my JS (main.js)

```
'use strict'; 
var App = angular.module( 'usersApp', ['ngResource'] );

App.config( function( $routeProvider ) {
    $routeProvider.
        when( '/', {
          controller:userListController,
          templateUrl:'list.html'
        }).
        when( '/user/:id', {
            controller:userDetailController,
            templateUrl:'detail.html'
        }).
        otherwise( '/' );
});


App.factory( 'myUsers', function( $resource ) {
    return $resource( 'users.txt' );    
});

var userListController = function( $scope, myUsers ) {
    $scope.users = myUsers.query();
};

var userDetailController = function( $scope ) {
    $scope.test = "testing Detail";
};
```

the results look something like this

```
ID  NAME    TYPE
-->     {"0":"["}           
-->     {"0":"{"}           
-->     {"0":"\""}          
-->     {"0":"i"}           
-->     {"0":"d"}           
-->     {"0":"\""}
```

I'll see if I can recreate in jsFiddle.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is invalid

```
[{"id":"284","name":"JAMES IS AAA-DRIVER","type":"Employee"},
 {"id":"243,"name":"Brian J Adamms","type":"Employee"},
 {"id":"237,"name":"Test Agent","type":"Brokerage Agent"}];
```

Notice the part `"id":"237` in the last line (you are missing an end quote).

I recommend you use [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) to check your JSON for validity.